# What is signature in the android and why it show me error "the signature is in debug mode"?

Tags: android, launching-application

There are lots of free android appmarket but *Mobogenie* is genuine and robust android application container but when i go to upload my android .apk file it is showing me a error **"the signature is in debug mode"**.

How can i fix it?

so what is signature in android?

Comment: [Consult the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Signature is an engine class which is capable of creating and verifying digital signatures, using different algorithms that have been registered with the Security class.
first import following..and then try to debuggled your methods this way..

```
import android.content.pm.Signature;  
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;  
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate; 

private static final X500Principal DEBUG_DN = new X500Principal("CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US");  
private boolean isDebuggable(Context ctx)
{ 
boolean debuggable = false;

try
{
    PackageInfo pinfo = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    Signature signatures[] = pinfo.signatures;

    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

    for ( int i = 0; i < signatures.length;i++)
    {   
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(signatures[i].toByteArray());
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(stream);       
        debuggable = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().equals(DEBUG_DN);
        if (debuggable)
            break;
    }
}
catch (NameNotFoundException e)
{
    //debuggable variable will remain false
}
catch (CertificateException e)
{
    //debuggable variable will remain false
}
return debuggable;
}
```